# Several bar charts of x-axis in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I need the bar charts to be on one x-axis and not on different graphs... Do you know how I can impruve the code so it will be on one axis?
Here is my code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
occ_data_monday= {"Occupancy Monday":[min_o_monday,mean_o_monday,max_o_monday,mean10_4_o_monday],
           "Statistics":["Minimum","Average","Maximum","Maximum Average"]
}

occ_data_tuesday= {"Occupancy Tuesday":[min_o_tuesday,mean_o_tuesday,max_o_tuesday,mean10_4_o_tuesday],
           "Statistics":["Minimum","Average","Maximum","Maximum Average"]
}

trace1 = go.Bar(x=["Minimum","Average","Maximum","Maximum Average"],
                                    y=(occ_data_monday["Occupancy Monday"]), 
                                    text=(occ_data_monday["Statistics"]),
                                    textposition="outside",
                                    texttemplate="%{y:.0%}",
                                    marker_color=occ_colours,
                                    width=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
)

trace2 = go.Bar(x=occ_data_monday["Statistics"],
                                    y=(occ_data_tuesday["Occupancy Tuesday"]), 
                                    text=(occ_data_tuesday["Statistics"]),
                                    textposition="outside",
                                    texttemplate="%{y:.0%}",
                                    marker_color=occ_colours,
                                    width=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
)

trace3 = go.Bar(x=occ_data_monday["Statistics"],
                                    y=(occ_data_tuesday["Occupancy Tuesday"]), 
                                    text=(occ_data_tuesday["Statistics"]),
                                    textposition="outside",
                                    texttemplate="%{y:.0%}",
                                    marker_color=occ_colours,
                                    width=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
)


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, specs=[[{}], [{}], [{}]],
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.001)


fig.append_trace(trace1, 3, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='')
fig
```

and here is what i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4JmY.png)

Comment: Why do you use subplot if you want it to be in the same x-axis in one plot?

Comment: Hi Arina, your example is not complete. The values in "Occupancy Monday" and "Occupancy Tuesday" are not defined